# Logging one file for each day in Azure

Tags: azure, logging, sitecore, log4net, logfile

This is related to Sitecore logging using log4net in Azure.

**Current Behavior**:

1. Multiple files getting created for the day.
2. The last file of the day is always of a different format(I have tried date tag to resolve..still its not working as expected)

Below are the three screenshots:

The log4net related setting just for azure
[image]

The only change which I have added at the moment.
[image]

Multiple files created for 20 Oct(i.e today) and last night file with weird name.
[image]

**Expected behavior**:
I want to log one file for each day irrespective of the number of restarts/application pool recycle with the date in the name of the file.

1. Just one file with date in the name included (eg.azure.log.20221020.084617.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update please, this error got resolved after I used the below code to resolve:

```
<appender name="AzureFallbackAppender">
            <rollingStyle>
                <patch:attribute name="value">Date</patch:attribute>
            </rollingStyle>
            <maximumFileSize>
                <patch:attribute name="value">50MB</patch:attribute>
            </maximumFileSize>
            <staticLogFileName>
                <patch:attribute name="value">false</patch:attribute>
            </staticLogFileName>
            <preserveLogFileNameExtension>
                <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
            </preserveLogFileNameExtension>
            <file>
                <patch:attribute name="value">D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data/logs/{machineName}/azure.log.{date}.{time}.txt</patch:attribute>
            </file>
            <appendToFile>
                <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
            </appendToFile>
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern>
                    <patch:attribute name="value">%4t %d - %-5p %m%n%n%n</patch:attribute>
                </conversionPattern>
            </layout>
        </appender>
```